# setFrame created an NSView that is 15 pixels smaller in both dimensions than expected

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview

I have a puzzling problem. I have a pointer to a vanilla NSView that was initialized in a nib. I messaged the NSView with:

```
[myNSView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,816,1056)];
```

but when I step through the debugger, `myNSView` has a frame of `{{0,0}, {801, 1041}}`. The dimensions of the rectangle are 15 less than I've specified! This happens consistently. If I specify two `[setFrames]` in a row, everything works, but of course that's not the answer.

Why does `setFrame` fail?

Comment: I have honestly no idea. This should work. Could you give more context?

Comment: I'm drawing custom content, say a page of text. I'm starting with a scroll view and an embedded in that is a page view. I have two actions, fit page and 100% view (similar to other viewers). I want to be able to zoom in and out. To do that, I change the frame size of the page view, and my hope is that scroll view will take care of panning around. It mostly works, except for the odd resizing behavior of the page view.

Comment: Hmm, the embedding could be messing around with your dimensions. Other than that, I still have no idea. Sorry. :) I voted the question up though, so perhaps somebody else can help you out. Good luck though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

15px is exactly the size of an NSScroller at NSRegularControlSize.

My guess is that you have your NSScrollView configured to automatically hide scrollers.

Try turning off the horizontal and vertical scrollers of your scrollView in the NIB, if that solves the problem, you'll know where to look from there.  It is something related to the clipView of the scrollView autoresizing the documentView.  The clipView itself is being autoresized when the scrollers appear; directly after you set the documentView to a frameSize (the 100% setting I'd guess) that requires scrollers.

Comment: That was brilliant, thank you so much!

I turned of the scrollers and everything fits now.

So, the reasoning is something like this:
1. I change the pageview size
2. scroll view updates to include scrollers
3. clipview resizes to accomodate scrollers and resizes subviews which includes pageview.

Right?

Comment: Yep, exactly :)  If you surround your setFrame: call with [[theScrollView contentView] setAutoresizesSubviews: NO]; and toggle it back on when done, I think that should do the trick.